# Off-topic with same search box

Tags: feature-request, migration, off-topic

I wanted to flag a question as off-topic  (*Flagging > Closing > Off-topic > Migration*), and point it to https://math.stackexchange.com/
but that option wasn't possible. There were only 5 options possible. 
Maybe **include the same search box** like you get when you click on the StackExchange header bar that says "**Find a StackExchange site"**.

Comment: FWIW the feature already exists, normal users just aren't allowed to use it.